# problems with java.util.Calendar and timeZones

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I have following method which convert my custom DMY (date,month,year) object to Date.

```
public static Date serverCreateDateFromDMY(DMY pDMY, TimeZone pTimeZone)
    {
        Calendar vCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(pTimeZone);
        vCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, pDMY.getYear());
            // Below line is because DMY month counts are 1-indexed
            // and Date month counts are 0-indexed
        vCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, pDMY.getMonthOfYear() - 1);
        vCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, pDMY.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println(vCalendar.getTime());
        TimeUtilsServer.zeroCalendarHoursAndBelow(vCalendar);
        System.out.println(vCalendar.getTime());
        return vCalendar.getTime();
    }


public static void zeroCalendarHoursAndBelow(Calendar pToZero)
    {
        pToZero.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        pToZero.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        pToZero.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        pToZero.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    }
```

to serverCreateDateFromDMY() method, I am passing these arguments : DMY=20120424, and TimeZone is : America/New_York. Application is running locally in my timezone which is IST.

based in above inputs, following output is printed.

```
Tue Apr 24 14:43:07 IST 2012

Tue Apr 24 09:30:00 IST 2012
```

so as you see that in last output time is not zeroed out. any suggestions please?

@Marko, yes I come to know about DateFormat and I tried following example. but still date is printed with time and not zeroing out.

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        Calendar vCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
        vCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);

        vCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4 - 1);
        vCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        df.setTimeZone(tz); 
        System.out.println(df.format(vCalendar.getTime()));

         vCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,     vCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        vCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, vCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
        vCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, vCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
        vCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,   vCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        System.out.println(df.format(vCalendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: How is TimeUtilsServer implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... and you are 9:30h ahead of NY time. You set the time to midnight NY time and read it out as time in your zone. Note that `getTime` returns a `Date`, which is not timezone-configurable. You'll need `DateFormat` if you want to specify the timezone for which you print the result.

Comment: Thanks Marko. yes I come to know about it. then I did simple example using DateFormat but it still not print date with zero time. I have character limitations under comment so I can not post entire example here.

Comment: The best way to proceed is to update your question to reflect your new work, both code and the new incorrect behavior. For context you can add it to the bottom and title it with **UPDATE**.

Comment: Yes I have updated my questions and added small example I did. It prints following 24 Apr, 2012 6:13:13 AM
24 Apr, 2012 12:00:00 AM

Comment: This is actually the correct output. What is confusing you is probably just the default date format, which uses the American AM/PM system. This output does represent 00:00 in the 24-hour format. See the Javadoc in `SimpleDateFormat` on specifying the date format.

Comment: Yes Marko, using SimpleDateFormat gave me correct display finally. Thanks for your feedback. here is the format I used.  `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss , zzzz");
  sdf.setTimeZone(tz);`

Answer (score 2):

java Date / Time API have a bad design from the time of its creation. Maybe you should take a look at some library - for example this which hides JDK API deficiencies - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi Bax. I agree with you. infact we are re engineering our product and we are replacing this clumsy java Date/Time API with joda time.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, Date and Calendar objects are stored in UTC. When you set the fields to 0, the Calendar is updated in UTC.

When you ask the Calendar for the time, it then converts the Date to your desired Timezone, hence the difference.

Comment: Date is always in UTC, never in system time zone.

Comment: Date is actually an absolute moment in time and it is the job of other classes to represent that moment how they see fit. It is also not true that Calendar get updated in UTC -- it is relative to the TimeZone you constructed it with. If you didn't use any TimeZone, then it's the system default TimeZone. Anyway, it's very convoluted.